# Force a terminal command to go via special http proxy

Tags: command-line, proxy

Is there any terminal command like torify for tor for http proxies so I can pass every connection a specific terminal command runs to pass through a special http proxy? 
I do not want to set environment variables as they Just don't work for me.

Comment: redsocks sets a global proxy, but not a per process proxy.

Comment: It may be useful to explain more about what you're trying to achieve. Do you want just commands such as wget and curl, which use HTTP, to go through the proxy, or other network commands such as netcat? I don't think exactly what you ask is possible, it doesn't really make sense, but perhaps there's a way to achieve your end goal.

Comment: @MarkSmith I am aware of how we can set an environment variable named `http_proxy` and hope the applications use that or set proxy for a command. but I think there should be a command like the `torify` command for tor which works the same for other proxies.

Comment: You can do this for IP  because there's a single way in the system of routing IP traffic.  Unfortunately there's no single place where all HTTP and only HTTP passes, where you could re-route it.  HTTP is an application, not a transport layer.  In any case, you'd only be able to route HTTP via an HTTP proxy, not network traffic in general.